# map inside another map react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I try to map inside another map, but I either get the error that says the variable declared for the map is not a function or I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). I did like a lot of answers on the other posts on stackoverflow but it doesn't work. Thank you for help.

exemple data:

```
product: [
  {
   id:1,
   name: "product1",
   description: "description product",
   color:[
     {
       id_color:1,
       color:"blue",
       quantity:"200ml"
     },
     {
       id_color:2,
       color:"Yellow",
       quantity:"500ml"
     }
  }
```

code

```
{product.map((data) =>
   <tr key={data.id} >
         <td >{data.name}</td>
         <td >{data.description}</td>
                                    
         {data.color.map((datas)=>{
           <tr key={datas.id_color} >
              <td >{datas.color}</td>
              <td >{datas.quantity}</td>           
           </tr>
         })              
        }                       
   </tr>                              
)}
```

Comment: Did you try to output / check with a debugger the received json (I guess?) as is instead of calling functions on it? You may also want to add types to the product array if you're using typescript…

Comment: Have you tried `Optional Chaining`? `data?.color.map((datas)=> {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. map function should return if it has multple lines
2. if you want to skip return then use parenthesis instead of {}

> ```
> {product.map((data) => (
>         <tr key={data.id}>
>           <td>{data.name}</td>
>           <td>{data.description}</td>
>           {data.color.map((datas) => (
>             <tr key={datas.id_color}>
>               <td>{datas.color}</td>
>               <td>{datas.quantity}</td>
>             </tr>
>           ))}
>         </tr>
>       ))}
> ```

Working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-i6zdht?file=App.tsx

Comment: Thank you so much for exemple @Codeur passionné

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much everyone @Omar Dié,  @Codeur passionné, @Nima and @DerMolly for your help, I think the problem comes from this : I saw in the console that I get the second array in this form in brackets without index:
I don't understand why this array is not getting an index

```
color:"[{
       id_color:1,
       color:"blue",
       quantity:"200ml"
     },
     {
       id_color:2,
       color:"Yellow",
       quantity:"500ml"
     }] "
```

Comment: I don't understand what you fixed, but good  if you found a solution. Maybe you want to consider to state the solution a bit more clearer and mark this as the answer…

Comment: I did not find a solution, I just realized that the second table is not recovering as such. So I think the problem comes from here @DerMolly

Answer (score 0):

you need to `return` if you are using `{}` in your map :

```
{product.map((data) =>
   <tr key={data.id} >
         <td >{data.name}</td>
         <td >{data.description}</td>
                                    
         {data.color.map((datas)=>{
           return(<tr key={datas.id_color} >
              <td >{datas.color}</td>
              <td >{datas.quantity}</td>           
           </tr>)
         })              
        }                       
   </tr>                              
)}
```

or you can remove `{}` from your code :

```
{product.map((data) =>
   <tr key={data.id} >
         <td >{data.name}</td>
         <td >{data.description}</td>
                                    
         {data.color.map((datas)=><tr key={datas.id_color} >
              <td >{datas.color}</td>
              <td >{datas.quantity}</td>           
           </tr>)              
        }                       
   </tr>                              
)}
```